# Native library load breakpoint in Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, gdb

How can I set a breakpoint to a native library load event in Android?

I would assume that setting a breakpoint on **dlopen()** would be a good starting point, however, the gdb cannot find the dlopen function even when the symbols for **libc.so** and **/system/bin/linker** are loaded.

It also looks like Android is using some special format of the .so files, as the nm tool does not report the **dlopen()** location either.

Is there any workaround for the problem or an Android-specific .so dump tool that can help locating the function address by its name so that I can set a breakpoint manually?

Edit:

What I'm trying to do is to set a breakpoint that should trigger when ANY native library is loaded, i.e. when any code (not even in my libraries) calls the **dlopen()** function.

The problem is that Android GDB does not support pending breakpoints. My scenario is like this:

1. I start my app and halt it.
2. The app is resumed and it loads my native library.
3. My function is called from the library (only once when the app is loaded).

If I set a breakpoint after #1, it won't work as the library is still not there and android-gdb won't be able to rebind it. If I let the program run, then halt it again and set a breakpoint, I'm already past #3, so that the breakpoint will be useless.

I'm trying to work around it by setting a breakpoint to **dlopen()** at #1 and then when it hits and loads the library (i.e. #2) I will set the actual breakpoint.

Using the normal ARM nm and objdump has no help. NM'ing the libc.so shows that **dlopen()** is undefined:

```
00016188 T dlmemalign
         U dlopen
00016338 T dlpvalloc
```

The **/system/bin/linker** binary physically contains the **dlopen** text (first byte of **.rodata** section), however **nm** shows the following text:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-nm.exe: linker: No symbols
```

Disassembling it with objdump gives no symbol names.

Googling around for android sources revealed this source file:

http://dexandroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bionic/linker/dlfcn.c

It looks like dlopen() is indeed defined inside /system/bin/linker, but it is using some non-standard symbol resolution mechanism (at least, based on the first comment):

```
/* This file hijacks the symbols stubbed out in libdl.so. */
```

So, coming back to the question, how can I set a breakpoint into **dlopen()** to set the actual breakpoint just when the library is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually any arm objdump should work, but there will be one in your ndk directory.
Even a non-arm readelf may work.

I'm not sure why you expect to find dlopen() in the library, unless it is explicitly using that to open another library - normally, one would think it would be called from libdvm.so at any rate I belive the implemention is in libdl.so (having a version of grep built for android is a very useful thing - you can find strings in the lib directory, though if you want to find if they are imports or exports you probably need to adb pull and objdump the files of interest).

If you are trying to breakpoint the library file being loaded, you might try implementing one of the static initializer functions (either C-level or the jni on load one) and putting a breakpoint there.

EDIT:

It turns out that objdump for arm does not decode the linkage via the plt used for symbols imported from shared libraries, though it does for some other platforms like x86.  This can make it very hard to make any sense of binaries which are stripped of debugging symbols, as you would expect from the system libs on the devices.  I was able to patch the binutils sources to do this for arm.  Eventually I hope to submit that somewhere, but in the meantime source of the patched version is available at https://github.com/cstratton/binutils-android-decodeplt

I put an objdump binary in a prebuilt-linux-x86/ directory though I don't know how portable that will be.

Comment: Unfortunately, objdump does not. Updated the question.

Comment: as I said before, it is in libdl.so and objdump works just fine if used correctly (posting from android device so not able to work out syntax for you right now)

Comment: It is indeed in libdl.so, however the libdl.so is not present in the library list (info shared) when the app is running.

Comment: Yes, libdl.so gets hijacked by the linker.   You may want to try to breakpoint the usage of dlopen in libdvm.so, the trick is that it's probably invoked indirectly through some arm code in the .plt which jumps to what the linker actually resolves, but objdump cannot sort that out, so you will not see dlopen() as a symbol in the dissasembly, instead it will be hiding as a reference to the first function name in the file minus some offset, ie pointing into the .plt.  I had something for decoding that for a project a year ago, trying to figure out where it got to.

Comment: I think the most practical think you could do would be to put an _init() function in your native library which logs something then enters an infinite loop.  That will give you a chance to manually break the program with gdb and continuing execution (or maybe raise a unhandled signal).

Comment: That won't do. I am making a Visual Studio plugin for NDK debugging, so the idea is to debug the startup code of any library without modifying it. Actually, it seems that it's possible to hook to it after manually analyzing the /system/bin/linker binary. I'll give it a try...

Comment: You'll eventually have to automate the analysis of /system/bin/linker though since it will be different on each build. I found my code for decoding the .plt table (such as in libdvm.so), spent some time trying to make it usable but have to temporarily suspend that effort for a while now.

Comment: I will indeed automate it. It's a relatively simple pattern matching algorithm.

Comment: Thinking about it more, not sure you really want to breakpoint dlopen() as there will be a lot of code to trace through before the library file actually gets loaded.   Maybe if you get the return ftom dlopen()... But that would be *after* initializers are called.  Perhaps you want the code that would call an initializer if it was present.

Comment: There actually is a designated place to put a breakpoint in the bionic linker which is exported via a struct gdb knows about (but ignores this member). But the real problem is that it is thumb code and ndk gdb can't breakpoint that without causing errors or confusing itself.

Comment: Interesting. Can you give me a link to more info about the struct?

Comment: Its in linker.h in the bionic sources

Comment: Thanks, looks like it works. With a pretty simple heuristic algorithm I can determine its location by parsing the linker binary. Will be better than hooking dlopen() that I did in the last version our tool.